# What is the difference between a final and a non-sealed class in Java 15's sealed-classes feature?

Tags: java, sealed-class, java-15, java-sealed-type

I have the following sealed interface (Java 15):

```
public sealed interface Animal permits Cat, Duck {

    String makeSound();
}
```

This interface is implemented by 2 classes:

```
public final class Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "miau";
    }
}

public non-sealed class Duck implements Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "quack";
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me the difference between `final` and `non-sealed`? `final` stops me from creating other sub-classes but what behavior does `non-sealed` apply to `Duck`?

Comment: [A permitted subclass may be declared non-sealed so that its part of the hierarchy reverts to being open for extension by unknown subclasses. (A sealed class cannot prevent its permitted subclasses from doing this.)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360)

Comment: A `final` class can never be subclassed (old, old functionality). A `non-sealed` class is specifically opening up a class to be subclassed, which is needed when its base class is `sealed`.

Comment: Sealing is a generalization of finality; a final class can be extended by nothing, a sealed class by the explicit list of permitted subtypes.  (A final class is like a selaed one with an empty permits list.)  Other languages have gone the route that a permitted subtype of a sealed type can be arbitrarily extended, but this often surprises people and can lead to bugs.  So Java requires you to be explicit about it: for a subtype of a sealed type, you have to pick one: final, sealed, or open for extension.  (Records are implicitly final so you don't have to say it explicitly.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- As you've marked `Cat` as `final`, no other class can extend `Cat`.
- As you've marked `Duck` as `non-sealed`, any class can extend `Duck`.

---

When marking a class as `sealed`, all directly extending classes (the ones after the `permits` clause) have to be marked either as `final`, `sealed` or `non-sealed`:

- Marking a class that extends a `sealed` class as `sealed`, applies the same effect on it: Only classes specified after the `permits` clause are allowed to extend it.
- `non-sealed` just "breaks the seal", so the effect doesn't have to be carried on down the hierarchy. The extending class is open (again) for being extended by unknown subclasses itself.
- `final` is *effectively* the same as `sealed` without any class specified after the `permits` clause. Notice that specifying nothing after `permits` is not possible, so `sealed` cannot replace `final`.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now. Every class can extend from a 'non-sealed' class :)

Answer (score 3):

**Final and non-sealed classes have some differences.**

**final class:** you can't inherit this class, it's impossible to extend this class to other class on the other hand.

**non-sealed class:** it's possible to inherit this class from others.

For example:
This sealed interface which interface only permitted for Cat & Duck class. Note that Cat & Duck must be final, non-sealed, or sealed class:

```java
public sealed interface Animal permits Cat, Duck {
    String makeSound();
}
```

Now, I am creating Cat & Duck class. Here Cat is the final class and another one is non-sealed class.

```java
public final class Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "miau";
    }
}

public non-sealed class Duck implements Animal {

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "quack";
    }
}
```

**So if you can try to inherit the Cat class, you can't, got compilation error because Cat class is final. On another hand, the Duck class is extendable because it's non-sealed class** Like,

```java
//Got Error
public class MyCat extends Cat {
    .......
}

//Error not show.Duck class is extendable
public class MyDuck extends Duck {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A final class has zero subclasses, meaning no other class can extend it.
Any class can extend the non-sealed class.

When you mark a class as sealed, only the permitted subclasses can extend it and can have only these modifiers final, sealed, or non-sealed:

```
public sealed class NumberSystem
    // The permits clause has been omitted
    // as all the subclasses exists in the same file.
{ }
non-sealed class Decimal extends NumberSystem { .. }
final class NonRecurringDecimal extends Decimal {..}
final class RecurringDecimal extends Decimal {..}
```

Though, the NumberSystem root level hierarchy is closed to set of known classes, you can allow the sub hierarchies to be open by using the non-sealed keyword.

The sealed and non-sealed combination allows you to restrict parts of your hierarchy but not all.

In the below diagram, we restricted the root hierarchy of the sealed class NumberSystem to a known set of subclasses. However, the [non-sealed](https://tedblob.com/sealed-classes-and-interfaces-in-jdk-17/) Decimal class allows any unknown subclass such as RecurringDecimal to extend it.